# MATLAB - Update private property in case of other property change

Tags: matlab, oop, properties, dependencies, private

I have a class with a dependent property that takes a while to be evaluated. For this reason, I would like it not to be evaluated every time it is queried, but only when the object is instantiated and when certain properties are changed. I have found [this interesting solution](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/53542-oop-how-to-avoid-recalculation-on-dependent-properties-i-hope-a-mathwork-developer-could-give-me-a) that is based on defining an extra private property that is set whenever necessary, with the dependent property taking the value of this extra private property.

Now the problem is: how can I make sure that this private property is set when the object is instantiated and it is automatically updated when certain properties of the object are changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed solution is perfect, just make sure that in your class constructor you define default value for both the dependent property and its proxy are set to a default value that fits your needs:

```
methods
    function this = MyClass(...)
        % default starting values for your properties 
        this.MyProperty1 = 0;
        this.MyProperty2 = -8;
        this.MyProperty3 = 3;

        % calculate the initial value of your dependent
        % property based on the default values of the other
        % properties (this is basically the computeModulus
        % function of your example)
        this.UpdateMyDependent();
    end
end
```

The logics that make your dependent property update when other properties are modified is already included in the linked thread, implement them in your class.

```
function this = set.MyProperty1(this,value)
    this.MyProperty1 = value;
    this.UpdateMyDependent();
end

function this = set.MyProperty2(this,value)
    this.MyProperty2 = value;
    this.UpdateMyDependent();
end

function UpdateMyDependent(this)
    this.MyDependentProxy = this.MyProperty1 * this.MyProperty2;
end

function value = get.MyDependent(this)
    value = this.MyDependentProxy;
end
```